# Images and database migration on production on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have started developing an app with rails, and just set up a VPS on digitalocean. I have followed everything about the server config and capistrano deployment.

I can now access my website and deployment goes fine, except that **my images are absent and my database is empty (but working)**.

What do I have to do to use my development database locally, and automatically put images and database in production mode on the vps when pushing ?

Comment: It might be because your development environment is not configured to store static assets.

Comment: Ahh ok, I think it's that, but it keeps js and css though

Answer (score 1):

For image upload use either use cloud hosting services like AWS or  Google Cloud Service or upload these images to folder that is not included in git ignore file.

For database , first up your local database and production database are two different things unless you use a common remote database
though there are ways to migrate your local db to production too , follow this link 
[Postgres Backup Digital Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451943/postgres-backup-digital-ocean)

Comment: Thanks, I figured why the database was empty and why it is logical ! And I already store images to aws but for static images (favicon, etc) how can I keep them when pushing ?

Comment: put them inside assets folder

Comment: They are already in asset folder. Css and Js work fine, but I can't acess images through /assets/image